# You don't have permission to access on this server. url parameter

Tags: php, permissions, internal-server-error

So I made a site, worked well and such. Now I looked at it again because soon I need to present it. But suddenly it gives me an

```
`Forbidden You don't have permission to access /test/index.php on this server.
Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`
```

When I try to reach `.../test/index.php?insertEdit=true` while when I go to `.../test/index.php?type=result` it works properly. Just the `insertEdit=true` gives that error while before it worked perfectly.

Comment: Have you tried looking for the problem in your web server's error log?

Comment: yea it says `all to undefined method stdClass::isSMTP() in ` but the mail method works. and this has **noting** to do with mailing or SMTP or anything in that region @mhawke

Comment: I also tried reuploading the files / change the `insertEdit` to `typeInsert` but nothing worked @mhawke

Comment: What has changed in your server's environment? What is your code doing differently in the two cases? `insertEdit=true` suggests a write operation which will require appropriate permissions. Have permissions been changed since it was last working? Is there a web application firewall front-ending the server?

Comment: I dont even know _how_ to change permissions. It is all in one file, so how can `type` work but `insertEdit` not , if it wouldnt have permission, it wouldnt have permission in the whole file, I would assume? @mhawke

Comment: So it is a **server** problem for sure and nothing wrong in my code? @mhawke

Comment: I haven't seen your code so can't comment on whether there is a problem there. But it does look like the problem is elsewhere. Possibly there is a WAF rejecting the requests?